# Why do I keep ending up on infinite loop?

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop

I keep ending up on a infinite loop even on do while loop!

What am I doing wrong? I tried everything but I still cant figure it it out. any help?

here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
//prototype for IsAccessible
int IsAccessible(string username, string password);

//prototype for menu
void menu();

int main()
{
    string username;
    string password;

    //make user to login
    cout << "Enter username : ";
    getline(cin, username);
    cout << "\nEnter Password : ";
    cin >> password;
    IsAccessible(username, password);
    cout << "Thank you for logging in!!";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

//function definitions 
//definition for IsAccesible
int IsAccessible(string username, string password)
{
    //check if user entered correct details
    do
    {
        int x = 0;
        if(password == "123" && username == "asdqw")
        {
            cout << "\n\nThank you for loggin in John!";
            break;
        }
        //if user entered wrong details
        else if(password != "123" && username != "asdqw")
        {
            cout << "\nYou have either entered a wrong password or username.\n";
            cout << "Please retry.";
        }
        //if user exceeds limitation 
        if(x == 5)
        {
            cout << "\n\nYou have exceeded the 5 retry limitations......\n";
            Sleep(4000);
            cout << "Exiting program....";
            Sleep(5000);
            return 0;
        }
    }while(password != "123" && username != "asdqw");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get input inside the while loop?

Comment: you have to do 'cin >> password;' in the loop if you want it to terminate.

Comment: Why do you think `do while` is inherently immune to infinite loops?

Answer (score 2):

The `while` will keep looping until the username is not "asqdf" and the password is not "123" and the code never asks for a fresh username & password, so it will just keep looping to infinity. Also, you don't increment`x` every time the loop iterates, so the 5-maximum-attempts code will never run.

Just a final tip - if your methods don't need to return, you can make the return type `void`. Instead of returning to exit the do-while, you could use a `break` statement.